# I cannot install pyopenjtalk "Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully."

Tags: python

I've been working on a VR AI chat bot however the one dependency I need is pyopenjtalk and it simply refuses to install.

```
Collecting pyopenjtalk
  Using cached pyopenjtalk-0.3.0.tar.gz (1.5 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [25 lines of output]
      setup.py:26: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
        _CYTHON_INSTALLED = ver >= LooseVersion(min_cython_ver)
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\ProgramData\miniforge3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 351, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\ProgramData\miniforge3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 333, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "C:\ProgramData\miniforge3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\re\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-a_tp6_20\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 162, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(
        File "C:\Users\re\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-a_tp6_20\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 143, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\re\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-a_tp6_20\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 267, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
        File "C:\Users\re\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-a_tp6_20\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 158, in run_setup
          exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
        File "setup.py", line 153, in <module>
        File "C:\ProgramData\miniforge3\lib\subprocess.py", line 503, in run
          with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
        File "C:\ProgramData\miniforge3\lib\subprocess.py", line 971, in __init__
          self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
        File "C:\ProgramData\miniforge3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1440, in _execute_child
          hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
      FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I assume the "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified" is the issue but I have no idea what file is not being found.

Can someone please help me as to why this keeps breaking?

I've tried everything from reinstalling python entirely, using different command lines, reinstalling cmake, cython and also ensuring I had C/C++ compilers which was specified in the requirements however it still does not install.

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered the same problem.
Refer to the Build Requirements of https://pypi.org/project/pyopenjtalk/

you can try in terminal one by one:

```
gcc (g++)
cmake
cython
```

Make sure they are all valid, fill in missing context

I was missing the cmake environment, I solved it after adding cmake to the Path environment variable
This is my "cmake" path I added to environment:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\
```

You need to make sure all three commands can be executed before executing

```
pip install pyopenjtalk
```